# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen wallpaper

Tags: unity, nautilus, compiz, desktop-environments, desktop-background

*( Sorry for any mistake, english isn't my native language )*

*Same problem as [Ubuntu 16.04 wallpaper under black screen, after login (unity 7.4.0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775939/ubuntu-16-04-wallpaper-under-black-screen-after-login-unity-7-4-0).*

Yesterday after I setup one of my hd partitions to mount on startup and reboot the system to test it, a black screen cover my wallpaper:

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot7xu.png*

But when the session is blocked, gets normal:

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7rM1.jpg*

I'm using numix theme, changing to default theme, Ambiance, the UI get a bit messed up :

*i.imgur.com/ld9vspQ.png*

Already try to reset settings and reinstall ubuntu desktop, nautilus, unity and compiz but nothing.

Anyone can help me?